# Attribute table display

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Does someone know how I can go back to my normal Attribute Table settings where I can see all my rownumbers and values?

[image]

Comment: Bottom right...

Answer (score 1):

These buttons toggle form view and table view:

[image]

Plenty of room for them in the top toolbar, not sure why they can't go there, submit a QGIS enhancement request maybe?